# Expected profit of drawing black and white beans where the payout is the proportional to the fraction of black beans drawn.

Tags: probability

You are playing a game where the maximum reward is \$100. There are 100 beans in a hat. 50 black and 50 white. You can continue to draw until all 100 beans are drawn or you can stop whenever.

When you stop, you get paid $100*\frac{d_b}{d_b+d_w}$ where $d_b, d_w$ is the number of black and white beans you've drawn. What is the expected profit? (I pasted this problem verbatim but it seems ambiguous. I think it's asking for the expected profit of the most optimal strategy)

Intuition:

(1)The minimum guaranteed profit is \$50 because you could always just draw all 100 beans and get paid \$50. This implies that any time the number of black beans drawn is less than or equal to the number of white beans, you should keep drawing.

(2) If you draw a black bean on the first try, you should obviously stop.

Now for the hard part. How do you figure out when to stop? If you draw 2 black beans and 1 white bean, should you stop, or take your chances?

Would it make sense to approach this problem in terms of evaluating all possible stopping criterions, i.e., stopping after 1 draw, 2, 3, 4, etc...?

For example, say the stopping criterion is 2 draws. The possibilities for the 2 draws are:

(1) Draw black bean then white (probability $0.5 * 50/99$)

(2) Draw white bean then black (probability $0.5 * 50/99$)

(3) Draw 2 white beans (probability $ 0.5 * 49/99$)

(4) Draw 2 black beans (probability $ 0.5 * 49/99$)

Then we can easily find the expectation. It seems like this would be a lot of work to think about all stopping criterions (unless there's some inductive approach), but it also seems that it's not valid because it seems if we fix the number of draws, then the strategy isn't adaptive. i.e., what if we fixed number of draws to be 3, and we draw 3 whites, we would obviously want to keep drawing in that scenario.

Comment: My intuition is that your strategy should be to stop as soon as you've drawn more black beans than white beans, or when you run out of beans, whichever comes first.  You won't ever want to stop after exactly two beans.  If your first bean was black, you'll stop without drawing the second.  If it was white, then at best you'll get back to $50-50$ and it can't cost, and can gain, to keep drawing beans.

Comment: @RobertShore Yeah that's my common sense intuition as well, but I'm not confident that there isn't a more optimal threshhold to go over.

Comment: @RobertShore If we assume this strategy is correct, is there an easy way to do the analysis for the expectation? Seems rather difficult

Comment: @RobertShore So I ran some monte carlo simulations, and found that the most optimal stopping criterion is actually when the number of blacks is 2 greater than number of whites (excluding the case where the first draw is white). For this case my expected profit is about $79.7. For the case where number of blacks is just greater than number of whites, it's slightly slower at 78.6.